# gnome software not working on fedora 24

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3, curl

Gnome software on fedora 24 is not working. It shows

```
Detailed errors from the package manager follow:

Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-24&arch=x86_64 [Connection timed out after 120001 milliseconds]
```

I tried updating, re-installing gnome-software and updating whole system but no avail. I also tried [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1188455#c3) this, but I guess `packagekit` service is working good. Output of `systemctl status packagekit.service -l` is

```
● packagekit.service - PackageKit Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/packagekit.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2016-10-15 17:10:49 IST; 3h 14min ago
 Main PID: 1593 (packagekitd)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/packagekit.service
           ├─1593 /usr/libexec/packagekitd
           └─8096 gpg-agent --homedir /var/cache/PackageKit/24/metadata/fedora-cisco-openh264.tmp/gpgdir --use-standard-socket --daemon

Oct 15 20:13:46 Fedora PackageKit[1593]: search-file transaction /243_daeccaaa from uid 1000 finished with success after 15ms
Oct 15 20:13:46 Fedora PackageKit[1593]: search-file transaction /244_baeadaad from uid 1000 finished with success after 15ms
Oct 15 20:13:46 Fedora PackageKit[1593]: search-file transaction /245_bccebeaa from uid 1000 finished with success after 14ms
Oct 15 20:13:47 Fedora PackageKit[1593]: get-details transaction /246_bcedacab from uid 1000 finished with success after 249ms
Oct 15 20:13:51 Fedora PackageKit[1593]: get-details transaction /247_ecdcdeba from uid 1000 finished with success after 11ms
Oct 15 20:13:52 Fedora PackageKit[1593]: get-repo-list transaction /248_ecddceed from uid 1000 finished with success after 1ms
Oct 15 20:13:53 Fedora PackageKit[1593]: uid 1000 is trying to obtain org.freedesktop.packagekit.package-install auth (only_trusted:1)
Oct 15 20:13:53 Fedora PackageKit[1593]: new install-packages transaction /249_cccdadbb scheduled from uid 1000
Oct 15 20:13:53 Fedora PackageKit[1593]: uid 1000 obtained auth for org.freedesktop.packagekit.package-install
Oct 15 20:15:53 Fedora PackageKit[1593]: install-packages transaction /249_cccdadbb from uid 1000 finished with failed after 120070ms
```